# Install quercus on ubuntu using tomcat

Tags: quercus

I have been trying to install quercus on ubuntu for quite a while now however i have to start again, can anyone advise on the best way of successfully installing quercus on ubuntu please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from here: http://wiki3.caucho.com/Quercus:_Tomcat

The Quercus WAR is ready to run on Tomcat by placing it inside Tomcat's webapps directory.